# How to get ACSII value of an integer in python?

Tags: python, ascii

I have something like this right now but this wont work because chr requires an integer. How can I make it print the chr of the user input?

```
num1 = input("Enter a ASCII code 0 - 127:")
print(str(chr(num1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the user input to `int` first -

```
num1 = input("Enter a ASCII code 0 - 127:")
print chr(int(num1))
```

(Incorporated @chepner's comment)

Comment: `chr` already returns a string; no need to call `str` on that value.